# Create a serverside file in Meteor

Tags: javascript, filesystems, meteor

I was wondering how to write files in Meteor to the server. I was looking at this NodeJS code, but it wasn't working when I tried it in the server javascript code.

```
    var fs = require('fs');
    fs.writeFile("/client/test", "Hey there!", function(err) {
    if(err)
        console.log(err);
    else
        console.log("The file was saved!");
    });
```

It was saying that require wasn't defined. Anyways, does anybody know how to write files to the server in Meteor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `Npm.require` instead of just `require`.

```
var fs = Npm.require('fs');
```

This will work for any module that is part of node or meteor (such as `fs` so its not a problem here). However, for other npm modules you would have to use [Meteor NPM](https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/npm) or write your own [smart package](https://atmosphere.meteor.com/wtf/package)